# Xamarin forms button send alternately boolean true or false on click

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, boolean

I am a novice in Xamarin,

I am looking for a way to send a
alternately  a boolean true/false when I click on a button

here is my button :

```
 <Button Text="sendTrueorFalse"   
         CommandParameter="{Binding BooleanTrueOrFalse }" 
         Clicked="OnSort" />
```

Here is my methode:

```
void OnSort(object sender,EventArgs e) {

        var item = (Button)sender;

        var myboolean = (Boolean)item.CommandParameter;

        if (myboolean) {
           //do true
        }


        if (!myboolean){
             //do false
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of passing the bool as a CommandParameter, just make it a class level variable, and flip it's value every time the button is clicked.

```
bool myBool = false;

void OnSort(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  // flip the value of myBool
  myBool = !myBool;

  if (myBool) {
    //do true
  } else {
    // do false
  }
}
```